# How can I extract features from pytorch fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn

Tags: pytorch, faster-rcnn

I tried to extract features from following code.
However, it says 'FasterRCNN' object has no attribute 'features'
I want to extract features with (36, 2048) shape features when it has 36 classes.
Is there any method to extract with pretrained pytorch models.

```
model = torchvision.models.detection.fasterrcnn_resnet50_fpn(pretrained=True).to(device)
features = list(model.features)

dummy_img = torch.zeros((1, 3, 800, 800)).float() # test image array

req_features = []
output = dummy_img.clone().to(device)

for feature in features:
    output = feature(output)
    if output.size()[2] < 800//16: # 800/16=50
        break
    req_features.append(feature)
    out_channels = output.size()[1]

faster_rcnn_feature_extractor = nn.Sequential(*req_features)

output_map = faster_rcnn_feature_extractor(dummy_img )
print(output_map.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you are calling returns a [`FasterRCNN`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/faster_rcnn.py#L43) object which is based on [`GeneralizedRCNN`](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py#L15). As you have experienced, this object doesn't indeed have a `feature` attribute. Looking at its source code, if you want to acquire the feature maps, you can follow [L83](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py#L83) and [L101](https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/main/torchvision/models/detection/generalized_rcnn.py#L101):

```
>>> images, _= model.transform(images, None)
>>> features = model.backbone(images.tensors)
```

Comment: Thank you! But I still don't know how to extract features with (36, 2048) from a image.
Sorry but could you give me some clue.

Comment: What are `36` and `2048` referring to?

Comment: 36 is number of classes and 2048 is input dimension before final fully-connected layer

Comment: Anyway, what i want is to extract the feature with shape (36, 2048) when the input image is like (3, 224, 224)

Comment: The backbone will return a spatial feature map, providing you with a feature vector per spatial location. You can use those features to train a downstream classifier on it.

Comment: Hmm, but when I test with this code, features = model.backbone(images.tensors) (images = torch.randn([1, 3,800,800]) here.
features['0'] : (1,256,200,200)
features['1']:  (1,256,100,100)
features['2'] : (1, 256, 50, 50)
...